# Express js authorization value undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two ports opened: 3000 and 4000. I want to pass the authorization header from 3000 and receive it on port 4000.

I'm passing authorization value from 3000 port

```
app.get('/',function(req,res){
  console.log('redirect');
  res.header('Authorization', 'my sample');
  res.redirect('http://localhost:4000/api/oauth2');
});
```

Receive on 4000 port

```
app.get('/api/oauth2', (req, res)=> {
  console.log(req.headers.authorization); // undefined
  res.end('i reached');
})
```

How would I receive this value from 3000 to 4000 port?

Comment: You setting `Authorization` and trying to access `authorization`. I think headers keys are case sensitive.

Comment: I changed, but its not working

Comment: You may want to log `req.headers` and see what that has.

Comment: `req` object of `'/'` isolate with `req` object of `'/api/oauth2'` , because you use `redirect` method ("Hey browser - client lets go to http://..." - the method said). Try use url query string instead set data to header. Headers just are  information of  a request or response, like `content-type` ...

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use request package from npm which is a http client.

```
npm install request
```

Import request module.

```
const request = require('request');

let options = { 
  url: "http://localhost:4000/api/oauth",
  headers:{
        authorization: "your_authorization_token"
   }

request.get(options, (err, response, body)=>{
// Handle response
})
```

Comment: Its sending data from port 3000 right? how would i receive at port 4000

Answer (score 0):

You can either return the '/' request with a .html file that makes a request on the client side, or you can set the auth token in the url query.